# Microsoft Access: Different Data Types Names in Designer View and SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, types

I am very new to MS Access.
I used the SQL query window in Access to create a table `Temp`,

`CREATE TABLE Temp(SO CHAR, Quantity INT, ETA DATE);`

then I open `Temp` 's designer view, I can see the columns and corresponding Access data type:

`SO-ShortText`     | (`CHAR->ShortText`)

`Quantity-Number` | (`INT->ShortText`)

`ETA-Date/Time`  | (`DATE->Date/Time`)

Well, now I know some date types' corresponding Access data type names, and my question is, where should I find the documentation stating these differences, and how do people know what Access data type to use when writing SQL queries in Access?

For example, now I want to create another table using SQL query and I want column `A` with `Currency` Access data type, column `B` with `Yes/No` Access data type, what would be their name in SQL? FYI, I tried `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` in SQL, but just failed to create the table.

Comment: I like Allen Browne's [Field Type Reference](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html).  If you want something from MS instead, do a search for "ms access sql data types".

Comment: Also don't use char columns. They will not trim blanks automatic - causing you great pain. Always use nvarchar for your text columns.

Comment: I have SQLServer Express which shows a Bit type and is seen as Yes/No field in Access. Review https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp